# the prototype of a function is Object.__proto__?

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
function a(){}
```

and:

```
console.dir(a.__proto__ === Object.__proto__) //true
```

shouldn't `a.prototype === Function OR a.prototype === Object`???

in case of  `a.prototype === Object` the engile would lookup it's prototype as wel so it would make more sense

Comment: The property `.prototype` is not the prototype of the function but a regular property of the functions. It references the prototype of the objects created by the function when it is use as a constructor (i.e. `a.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(new a())`). Read about it in the [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it cannot be obvious, but it makes sense if you think more about it. The prototype of the function is equal to the prototype of the Object, so we can say a function prototype connects with the prototype object but **NOT** the Object itself. They can be connected together and inherited with prototypes. I attached a diagram so take a few minutes to analyze that.

[Object prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

[image: THE PROTOTYPE CHAIN]